# Reading and increasing a number in a textfile with ++ or equivalent

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read a number from a file with Get-Content and adding it to a variable.

Then i add this number to a string in a file, increase the number by 1, then save that to the file again.

I have tried something like:

```
$i = Get-Content C:\number.txt
$i++
Set-Content C:\number.txt
```

The content of number.txt is: 1000

But i get this error:

```
The '++' operator works only on numbers. The operand is a 'System.String'.
At line:2 char:5
+ $i++ <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (1000:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperatorRequiresNumber
```

Does anyone have any idea of a better way of doing this operation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you need to convert it to an integer before increment it.

```
$str = Get-Content C:\number.txt
$i = [System.Decimal]::Parse($str)
$i++
Set-Content C:\number.txt $i
```

Answer (score 6):

short way:

```
[decimal]$i = Get-Content C:\number.txt # can be just [int] if content is always integer
$i++
Set-Content C:\number.txt $i
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it in one line:

```
 [decimal] ( $i = Get-Content C:\number.txt ) | % {Set-Content C:\number.txt -value ($_ + 1); return ($_ + 1)}
```

Returns the value incremented. $i has the value before the increment.